# Improving the manipulation of 2D Arrays for an easy challenge on HackerRank with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matrix

I am practicing some exercises on HackerRank in order to improve my skills on **Python3**. I am doing the 30 days challenge. There is one challenge involving matrices. I was able to pass the test cases and provide the correct result. However, I think my code could have huge improvements.

I am not really sure about how would be the best way to iterate over matrices to solve the problem asked. That's the challenge:

[image]
[image]

That's my code:

```
import sys

matrix_input = sys.stdin.readlines()
#print (matrix_input)

def make_matrix(matrix):

    final_matrix = []

    for line in matrix:

        #remove new_line
        line = line.strip()

        #remove space
        line = line.split(" ")

        #convert string to int
        line = list(map(int,line))

        final_matrix.append(line)

    return (final_matrix)

"""the function is going to receive a hour glass and return the sum of its elements. The easiest way is to treat things as a rectangle and make the elements on the second line, first col and last col, null, like zero"""

def sum_hour_glass_rec(hour_glass_rec):

    hour_glass_rec[1][0]=0

    hour_glass_rec[1][2]=0

    total = 0

    for linha in hour_glass_rec:
        for coluna in linha:
            total = total + coluna

    return total

def make_list_hour_glasses(matrix):

    A = matrix

    col_var= 0 
    list_part_hour_glass_iter = []
    list_hour_glasses = []
    k_var_iter = 0

    for k in range(0,4):
        col_var = 0
        for j in range(0,4):
            #print (j,"j")  
            for col in range(k_var_iter,k_var_iter+3):
                #print (col,"col")
                #print (A[col][col_var:col_var+3])
                list_part_hour_glass_iter.append(A[col][col_var:col_var+3])
                #print (list_part_hour_glass_iter)
                list_hour_glasses.append(list_part_hour_glass_iter)
            list_part_hour_glass_iter = []
            #print (list_hour_glasses)
            col_var+=1
        k_var_iter +=1

    return list_hour_glasses

matrix_of_recs = (make_list_hour_glasses(make_matrix(matrix_input)))

records = []

for rectangle in matrix_of_recs:
    records.append(sum_hour_glass_rec(rectangle))

maximum_record = max(records)

print(maximum_record)
```

In order to execute this, I created another file, called `d11_input.txt` with the input values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36
```

My command on terminal would just be:

```
python3 d11.py < d11_input.txt
```

Points that I suspect could have huge improvements:

1 - I treated the hourglass as a square and then, made two elements A21 and A23 zero. Maybe there is a more elegant way to do that.

2 - I used a three nested loop in order to generate all hour glasses a 6x6 matrix can have. Not good in terms of big O notation. Is there a way better?

3 - As you might see, when generating all possible hour glasses, each one was repeated three times which means I am calculating things that I do not need. Nonetheless, I was not able to fix this and also keep the rest of the code working. Here you see a picture of the "problem" involving repeated data that I am talking about:

[image]

I hope I will learn with your comments. Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Generating all possible hourglasses

Don't :-) It's a lot of memory and processing churn.

A more efficient alternative is to write a function that takes as parameters a matrix and the starting position of an hourglass, and return the sum of values at the appropriate relative positions:

```
def compute_hourglass_sum(matrix, top, left):
    return sum(matrix[top][left:left+3]) + ...
```

The caller is responsible for passing parameters to valid hourglasses.

As for the unnecessary recomputing of sums of overlapping hourglasses, given the small sizes of hourglass dimensions, I don't think it's worth it to come up with something more clever.

However, if the dimensions became significantly bigger, then that would indeed make sense. Perhaps *prefix sums* would be useful for that. I suggest to check out the concept, it's very interesting stuff.

#### Processing the input

In `make_matrix` it's not so great that the input parameter is named `matrix` when in fact it's just unprocessed text. I'd name it `input`. And then the local `final_matrix` variable could be renamed to simply matrix.

And I would rewrite the function with a list comprehension:

```
return [map(int, line.split()) for line in input]
```

(Thanks [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/graipher) for simplifying `line.strip().split(" ")` to `line.split()`.)

#### Minor things

There is an official coding style guide for Python called PEP8. I suggest to check it out. There is a command line tool that can check your code.

There are some redundant parentheses here and there. I suggest to remove them. The `pep8` tool can pinpoint them for you.

The default start value of `range(...)` is 0, so instead of `range(0, 4)` you can write simply `range(4)`.